# Get notification in view when a web API called from an external system in c# MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, notifications

I'm developing a website in C# MVC including WEB API. When an API URL in my project is called from an external system, I want to show a message (not a push message, only show a text in a div) in one of my view that the API function is executing.Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you done so far to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Of All its possible yes, 
you need To use SignalR To notify the Views:

YouTube totrual [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kr8uHeNjOKw&list=PL_c9BZzLwBRKJugyyAdhBoAPRs1DdaS7n)

Github : [Here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

Then You use the Signal R to push a Notification when a cross origin request happen
using action filters

the signalR subscribers can be view pages using Jquery.
[SignalR on Client](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client)

full exmaple :[here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3690/signalr-examples.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is posssible. One (pretty easy) way is to use the awesome SignalR or SignalR core framework. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for differences. Real-time web functionality enables server-side code to push content to clients instantly.

Basically you will create a Hub on the server that clients connect to. In your WebApi method, you can then call the client method. Then in the client you will use javascript to respond to the server call and then you will set the div content from this method.

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think Signal R is best choise too. But maybe you want to another alternative. You can look at Node Js.

[Node js.org](https://nodejs.org/en/)

[General Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/)

[General Tutorial 2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/)

[For .NET Tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/093731/nodejs-for-net-developer451/)